# Regex to validate wildcard domains with special conditions

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am looking to validate **wildcards** against Samsung Knox Firewall. Please see below the full criteria for all domains:

> > A list of URLs for specified domain names to block DNS resolution. The format of the URL must be compliant with RFC's standards and must also match one of the following rules:
> >
> > - Full URL: "www.google.com"
> > - Partial URL: "*android.com"; "www.samsung*"; "*google*". The
> >       character "*" (wildcard) must be at the beginning and/or at the end
> >       of the URL otherwise the URL is invalid.
> > - Special case, matches any URL : "*"

**Valid domains**

The following examples are considered valid by Knox.

- *.test.com
- *test.com
- *test
- *test*
- test.*
- test1.test.*

**Invalid domains**

The following examples are considered invalid by Knox.

- *test-
- *test.
- *test.com-
- *test-.com

Is anybody able to offer a hand? I am struggling to accommodate for all of the requirements with this one.

Current code:

```
(?=^\*|.*\*$)^(?:\*\.?)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9-]+(?(?=\.)(?<!-)\.(?!-)))+[a-z]+)(?:\.?\*)?$
```

Edit: Actually, it looks like conditional regex may not even be supported in Java.

Comment: I think all the "invalid" strings you provided, if run through your standard wildcard engine, would allow strings through that are not valid urls - did you notice that? no empty parts or hyphens at the end of parts

Comment: When Knox Firewall encounters an invalid domain or wildcard, rather than skip the invalid string, it errors out the entire process and gives no indication of which domain was invalid. The response is simply "invalid domain" after trying to add a set of, say, 5k rules. It may add 1 domain, it may add 4999, but it doesn't handle errors too well.

Comment: so you're trying to pre-filter the domains?

Comment: Yes! Extracting only those that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

### BASED ON YOUR PROVIDED EXAMPLES

If you're trying to pre-filter the domains, then this one matches all of your "Valid" examples and rejects all of your "Invalid" examples

`^[\w*]([\w*-]+[\w*])?(\.[\w*]([\w*-]+[\w*])?)*$`

If there's a file or carriage return separated field with all of these in it that you're trying to test, you may want to use the "multiline" switch like so:

`(?m)^[\w*]([\w*-]+[\w*])?(\.[\w*]([\w*-]+[\w*])?)*$`

since you tagged java, that would be encoded into a java string as follows:

`"(?m)^[\\w*]([\\w*-]+[\\w*])?(\\.[\\w*]([\\w*-]+[\\w*])?)*$"`

### EDIT - Matching all the rules, in addition to your provided examples

This expression seems to work:

```
^(\*|(\*|\*\.)?\w+(\.\w+)*(\.\*|\*)?)$
```

Matching/Non-matching examples:

```
      MATCHING             NON-MATCHING
    ------------           ------------
    *                      *test-
    *.test.com             *test.
    *test.com              *test.com-
    *test                  *test-.com
    *test*                 test*.com
    test.*                 test.*com
    test1.test.*           -test.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although this does match match the examples given above, it doesn't quite get it right; the wildcards must be at the start and/or end.


I have been tweaking mine a little:
`(?=^[*]|.*[*]$)(?:\*(?:\.|-)?)?(?:(?!-)[\w-]+(?:(?<!-)\.)?)+([a-z])+(?:(?:-|\.)?\*)?$`


Is there a way to simplify mine or adapt yours to suit? I am still learning the ropes with Regex.